# Unit tests connectionstring error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working in MVC application. I have this in my context class:

```
    public ProductsContext()
        : base("ProductyDB")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<ProductsContext>(null);
    }
```

my web.config connection string looks like this:

```
<add 
      name="ProductyDB"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
      connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLSERVER2008R2;Initial Catalog=ProductyDB;Integrated Security=True"/>
```

it works fine in MVC applicationbut as soon as I used the entities and function in a new Unit test project added to this solution from this MVC application, I get errors like tblProduct not available.

Temporary workaround: If I comment the following  lines from my ProductsContext:

public ProductsContext()
            : base("ProductyDB")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(null);
        }

and change my web.config connection string name to ProductsContext, It works.

Comment: My guess would be that your application for unit testing doesn't have an app.config that contains the connection string...what are you using for Unit Testing?

Comment: I have added an app.config in Unit test project and has connectionstring in it like: <add 
      name="ProductyDB"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
      connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLSERVER2008R2;Initial Catalog=ProductyDB;Integrated Security=True"/>

Comment: This issue is close to your
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471148/testing-connection-string-is-missing

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue similar to this one and it turns out I had an outdated/incorrect table name set in the `DbContext` class declaration. Probably a unique mistake, but my code was working properly for everything except the unit tests.

```
public ProductsContext()
    : base("ProductyDB") //This pointed at the wrong database name
{
    Database.SetInitializer<ProductsContext>(null);
}
```

I thought it was the ConnectionString name that you were supposed to put in, but it really was the `Initial Catalog` you were passing in.