# Testing - Connection string is missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-config, connection-string, integration-testing

Visual studio created a unit test project for me based on a method (right-click add test).  When I try to access the database, I get an exception.  Ran this code to see what my connection was:

```
ConnectionStringSettings connStringSettings = ConfigurationManager.
    ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"];
```

but, `connStringSettings` is null.  Upon inspection, ConnectionStrings collection has a count of only one.  It seems to not be reading from my web.config.

My DAL is isolated and cannot have its connection string set through code.  Its connection string is set in code like this:

```
set
{
    value = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
        ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
}
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: If you're accessing the database, you're not unit testing, you're integration testing. For a unit test, you should mock out your data access layer, at which time the connection string aspect is irrelevant.

Comment: @DBM - Good point. I updated tags and title.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Add an `App.config` file to your unit testing project and copy over the connection string from the `Web.config`.

#### Update: Better Solution

While adding a config will solve the immediate problem, it still results in unit tests depending on an actual database connection, which is not great. The better way to solve this problem is to mock the DAL entirely and pass that into the services which are using it.

Microsoft provides some guidance on that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/testing/mocking). It takes a little more time to setup, but it allows tests to be much more contained and complete.

I have had success using [`MockQueryable`](https://github.com/romantitov/MockQueryable/tree/master/src/MockQueryable) for mocking individual tables within a test data context.

Comment: Is this still the only viable solution (haven't found anything to say otherwise so far...but I haven't found a whole anyway). What if I can my connection string? I then have to make sure it's changed in the test project too?

Comment: Yep - sorry, but if your connection string is already automatically wrapped by the test class, there's nothing you can do about it. If there's an overload for the DAL constructor that you can instantiate using a customer connection string, then you could just put the string in that constructor. Unfortunately, if you have to change your connection string, you'll have to manually do it in both projects. Ultimately, though, the final answer is that unit tests really *shouldn't* be accessing databases, so the connection string technically shouldn't be needed there at all.

Comment: How do you test your queries are working then, if you're not meant to access the database?

Comment: Essentially, you need to mock the data context. One way of doing this would be to pass in a `Mock` object from moq, but that could get tough if queries get complex. For difficult queries, my preference is to completely mock the data context with a fake data context wrapper. There are a few stack questions about that, but one of them links here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2008/05/04/mocks-nix-an-extensible-linq-to-sql-datacontext.aspx

Comment: And it's still the answer in December 2015

Answer (score 8):

Excellent this worked for me. I have added App.config file under unit test project. But make sure that we shoud follow the synatx otherwise it will throw exception.

```
<connectionStrings>

    <add name="test" connectionString="" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

    <add name="db" connectionString=""" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Great Solution, worked for me as well.

Answer (score 5):

Add a connection string in the unit test's app.config file.   The unit test project isn't going to have access to your web project's web config.

Answer (score -3):

Another solution is to go to the solution property pages (solution->properties)

Startup Project - check the single startup project is the one with the config.

Select, ok - done.