# Test class can't find connection string

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I'm writing some integration tests in .NET Core, and I can't get the tests to run because the connection string is returning null. My code in `Startup.cs` is below, and I did copy `appsettings.json` to the tests project as per [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471148/testing-connection-string-is-missing). What am I missing?

**EDIT:** I figured out how to step through unit tests, and the environment is being set as Production even though I explicitly set `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to `development` in both the test and main projects. I'm building in debug mode. I don't know where I should be setting this. Either way, it should be pulling in a value and not null--both `appsettings.development.json` and `appsettings.production.json` have a string, and the generic `appsettings.json` is below (same as development).

**EDIT 2:** The test project seems to be completely ignoring any configuration I set. It's running the main project's `Startup` regardless of whether I tell it to or not. I removed all references to it and it's still attempting to run it.

`Startup.cs`:

```
public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();

    Configuration = builder.Build();
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDatabase")));
}
```

`appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyDatabase": "Server=localhost;Database=MyDevLocal;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share the repo. Tricky part is setting up the project referencing the dotnet core project in a way that when you run the test you are indeed triggering the config builder. Also it depends on how are you consuming the connection string.

Comment: @lazy This is closed-source, unfortunately, so I can't share the repo. I can share pretty much whatever you need, but the repo is private.

Comment: I suppose it's an integration test? How do you startup your asp.net application within the unit test project? Are you building a TestServer like in this example https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Ahoy/blob/master/test/Swashbuckle.IntegrationTests/SwaggerGenIntegrationTests.cs#L50-L56 ?

Comment: @vaindil how are you triggering the unit tests?

Comment: @lazy I'm using xunit and calling from Test Explorer, as explained in [this documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/testing/integration-testing.html).

Comment: @vaindil so the line of var builder is hit while running the test. Can you inspect to make sure your env.ContentRootPath is set to the path where appsettings is located. When running the tests where ever you are running from env variable might have different properties

Comment: @lazy Huh, you're right. When I run normally, the root path is `src\WebProject`, but when testing it's `test\TestProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0`.

Comment: @Tseng I somehow completely missed your comment, I'm sorry. The method in that link is probably what I'll have to do. Right now it just pulls the default `Startup.cs` config, but I'll probably need to manually configure it.

Comment: you need to set the environment variable on the console: 
set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development

Comment: @Tseng My test class is completely ignoring all configuration I set. It's running the main project's `Startup` regardless of what I set in the test class. I removed all references to the main `Startup` class but it's still being run.

Comment: @lazy My previous comment may be helpful (can only mention one person per comment).

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me

`var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
.UseStartup<Startup>()
.UseSetting("ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection", /*Your conn string*/)`

Answer (score 4):

1. Install the NuGet Packages to your test Projects i.e.
   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer and Microsoft.AspNetCore
2. Copy and paste(or a new) appsettings.json file to your test project contains..

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "YourConnection": "Data Source=.\\SqlExpress;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True;"
    }
}
```

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

    public class YourTestServicesShould
    {
        private YourContext _yourContext; //TODO DI
        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }
        [Fact]
        public void Save_WhenGivenAValidOrderItem()
        {
            //Arrange
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
            Configuration = builder.Build();

            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<_yourContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("YourConnection"));
            _yourContext= new YourContext(optionsBuilder.Options);

    ....

   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I could moan about living on the bleeding edge of software development, but I won't since I'm just working on a personal project. I was getting the same symptoms about connection string not set in my API project (which references Entity Framework), so here's what worked for me with an example MyAPI project.

1. Overall solution folder as MyApi, with src and test at the same level within.
2. Then create project test\MyApi.IntegrationTests and copy appsettings.json from src\MyApi to test\MyApi.IntegrationTests

Then you can create the test as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xunit;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;

namespace Tests
{
    public class MyAPIRequestsShould
    {
        IWebHostBuilder _webHostBuilder;
        TestServer _host;
        HttpClient _client;

        public MyAPIRequestsShould()
        {
            string curDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            _webHostBuilder = new WebHostBuilder().UseContentRoot(curDir).UseStartup<MyApi.Startup>();
            _host = new TestServer(_webHostBuilder);
            _client = _host.CreateClient();
        }

    private dynamic newTestRegistration(string mobileCountryCode = "44", string fullMobile = "447900123456", string firstName = "Scooby", string surname = "Doo", DateTime? registeredAt = null)
    {
        return new { mobileCountryCode = mobileCountryCode, fullMobile = fullMobile, firstName = firstName, surname = surname, registeredAt = (registeredAt == null ? DateTime.UtcNow : (DateTime)registeredAt) };
    }

        [Fact]
        public async Task Return422WhenCountryCodeTooLong() 
        {
            object requestData = newTestRegistration(mobileCountryCode);
            var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestData), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            // Exercise the fluent validation
            var response = await _client.PostAsync("api/appusers/registration", content);
            Assert.Equal(422, (int) response.StatusCode);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using the Startup class from MyApi to initialize the host, but the key thing is the use of 'UseContentRoot(curDir)' in the test constructor. Before this, env.ContentRoot was set to some bin folder. Now it finds the test version of the appsettings.json file, and I like the fact that I can point it to an integration version of my database just by changing the connection string.

I didn't know how to debug tests from within Visual Studio, so for a bonus, it's: Test -> Debug -> Selected Tests | All Tests

Comment: I'm so glad that i stumbled upon this. Finally, something worked!!!! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and got it working by first copying over the appsettings.json file to my test project and setting output to always copy.  Then In my test setup I did the following:

```
 string curDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(curDir)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

        var webBuilder = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseContentRoot(curDir).UseConfiguration(builder.Build())
            .UseStartup<Startup>();


        var server = new TestServer(webBuilder);

        _client = server.CreateClient();
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste your appsettings.json in Test project and make sure that your have following code in your Startup file constructor.

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
           // Configuration = configuration;

            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
                Configuration = builder.Build();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem in Asp .Net Core 2.2 Where I execute the tests from Visual studio and the configuration file is missing. Obviously I need to set the path of the `appsettings`, but `UseContentRoot()` is not working for me. The solution for me was:

```c#
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
  .AddJsonFile(appSettingsPath)
  .Build();

var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
  .UseConfiguration(configuration)
  .UseStartup<Web.Startup>();
```