# ASP.NET Unit-Test : A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing

I'm creating a Unit Test Project for a ASP.Net Web Application using MVC in Visual Studio. But when I run the test, I have this error
[image]

```
Message: 
 Test method TestProjectKCPM.UnitTest1.TestMethod1 threw exception: 
    System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file D:\Code\Visual Studio\FinalProject_CNPM\FinalProject\TestProjectKCPM\bin\Debug\CNPM.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.
```

I have enter the link that the error recommend and can't seems to help.

Comment: I think your problem is `Connection String`. Perhaps this link useful for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/9471161/7834019

Comment: Oh yes I've solved it and this new error emerge.

    Test method TestProjectKCPM.UnitTest1.TestMethod1 threw exception: 
    System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: add more detail of new error